# What strategies are there for escaping character entities?

Tags: character-encoding, escaping

We are doing Natural Language Processing on a range of English language documents (mainly scientific) and run into problems in carrying non-ANSI characters through the various components. The documents may be "ASCII", UNICODE, PDF, or HTML. We cannot predict at this stage what tools will be in our chain or whether they will allow character encodings other than ANSI. Even ISO-Latin characters expressed in UNICODE will give problems (e.g. displaying incorrectly in browsers). We are likely to encounter a range of symbols including mathematical and Greek. We would like to "flatten" these into a text string which will survive multistep processing (including XML and regex tools) and then possibly reconstitute it in the last step (although it is the semantics rather than the typography we are concerned with so this is a minor concern).

I appreciate that there is no absolute answer - any escaping can clash in some cases - but I am looking for something allong the lines of XML's `<![CDATA[ ...]]>` which will survive most non-recursive XML operations. Characters such as `[` are bad as they are common in regexes. So I'm wondering if there is a generally adopted approach rather than inventing our own.

A typical example is the "degrees" symbol:

```
HTML Entity (decimal)   &#176;
HTML Entity (hex)   &#xb0;
HTML Entity (named)     &deg;
How to type in Microsoft Windows    Alt +00B0
Alt 0176
Alt 248
UTF-8 (hex)     0xC2 0xB0 (c2b0)
UTF-8 (binary)  11000010:10110000
UTF-16 (hex)    0x00B0 (00b0)
UTF-16 (decimal)    176
UTF-32 (hex)    0x000000B0 (00b0)
UTF-32 (decimal)    176
C/C++/Java source code  "\u00B0"
Python source code  u"\u00B0"
```

We are also likely to encounter TeX

```
$10\,^{\circ}{\rm C}$
```

or

```
\degree
```

so backslashes, curlies and dollars are a poor idea.

We could for example use markup like:

```
__deg__
__#176__
```

and this will probably work but I'd appreciate advice from those who have similar problems.

**update** I accept @MichaelB's insistence that we use UTF-8 throughout. I am worried that some of our tools may not conform and if so I'll revisit this. Note that my original question is not well worded - read his answer and the link in it.

Comment: It's pretty hard to comment on this if you don't mention any architecture or programming languages. How do you intend to store the documents? Where is the problem? In your internal architecture? In your file loaders?

Comment: @xcut: I think the problem is that when you filter and manipulate the data at a general level, you don't have a clearly defined way of "tagging" these entities so to prevent they are not mingled by these filters down the pipe. Near the data source, the type of data and the escaping is known, but at a more general level, you need a very generic, very robust delimiter/tagging to prevent destruction by a very generic filter.

Comment: @xcut the diagnosis from @Stefano is correct. We do not know what tools these will go through. For example we used to use the NLTK (Python) toolkit and have now switched part of that to Java (ANTLR). Next month we may need something different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Get someone to do this who really understands character encodings. It looks like you don't, because you're not using the terminology correctly. Alternatively, [read this](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).
- Do not brew up your own escape scheme - it will cause you more problems than it will solve. Instead, **normalize the various source encodings to UTF-8 (which is really just one such escape scheme, except efficient and standardized)** and handle character encodings correctly. Perhaps use UTF-7 if you're really that scared of high bits.
- In this day and age, not handling character encodings correctly is not acceptable. If a tool doesn't, abandon it - it is most likely very bad quality code in many other ways as well and not worth the hassle using.

Comment: My last comment disappeared... Could you please indicate where I am using terminology correctly and I will try to learn.

Comment: You're mixing up a standard defining abstract characters (Unicode), concrete encodings (ASCII, ISO-Latin) and file formats (PDF, HTML, which support arbitrary encodings). You're using the unqualified term "ANSI" which has various conflicting meanings. You say "ISO-Latin characters expressed in UNICODE", which is completely backwards. Do read the article I linked to carefully, it should make things clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I don't get the problem correctly, but I would create a very unique escape marker which is unlikely to be touched, and then use it to enclose the entity encoded as a base32 string.

Eventually, you can transmit the unique markers and their number along the chain through a separate channel, and check their presence and number at the end.

Example, something like

`the value of the temperature was 18 cd48d8c50d7f40aeb6a164181b17feee EZSGKZY= cd48d8c50d7f40aeb6a164181b17feee`

your marker is a uuid, and the entity is &deg encoded in base32. You then pass along the marker cd48d8c50d7f40aeb6a164181b17feee. It cannot be corrupted (if it gets corrupted, your filters will probably corrupt anything made of letters and numbers anyway, but at least you can exclude them because they are fixed length) and you can always recover the content by looking inside the two markers.

Of course, if you have uuids in your documents, this could represent a problem, but since you are not transmitting them as authorized markers along the lateral channel, they won't be recognized as such (and in any case, what's inbetween won't validate as a base32 string anyway).

If you need to search for them, then you can keep the uuid subdivision, and then use a proper regexp to spot these occurrences. Example:

```
>>> re.search("(\w{8}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{12})(.*?)(\\1)", s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1003d31f8>
>>> _.groups()
('6d378205-1265-44e4-80b8-a47d1ceaad51', ' EZSGKZY= ', '6d378205-1265-44e4-80b8-a47d1ceaad51')
>>>
```

If you really need a specific "token" to test, you can use a uuid1, with a very defined specification of a node:

```
>>> uuid.uuid1(node=0x1234567890)  
UUID('bdcce554-e95d-11de-bd0f-001234567890')
>>> uuid.uuid1(node=0x1234567890)  
UUID('c4c57a91-e95d-11de-90ca-001234567890')
>>>
```

You can use anything you prefer as a node, the uuid will be unique, but you can still test for presence (although you can get false positives).

Comment: You do understand the problem precisely and your solution is logical. I don't mind the length, and we could put symbolic constants in the code. However there is not clear lexical indication of when these entities start and end - you can't for example search for them.